# Tensorflow - classify based on multiple image as input, not signle one

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building CNN that will tell me if a person has brain damage. I'm planning to use [tf inception v3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/inception) model, and [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) script to build *TFRecord*.

Dataset is composed of brain scans. Every scan has about 100 images(different head poses, angles). On some images, damage is visible, but on some is not. I can't label all images from the scan as a damage positive(or negative), because some of them would be labeled wrong(if scan is positive on damage, but that is not visible on specific image).

Is there a way to label the whole scan as positive/negative and in that way train the network? 
And after training is done, pass scan as input to network(not single image) and classify it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like multiple instance learning might be your approach. Check out these two papers:

[Multiple Instance Learning Convolutional Neural
Networks for Object Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03155.pdf)

[Classifying and segmenting microscopy images
with deep multiple instance learning](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4908336/pdf/btw252.pdf)

The last one is implemented by @dancsalo (not sure if he has a stack overflow account) [here](https://github.com/dancsalo/TensorFlow-MIL).

I looks like the second paper deals with very large images and breaks them into sub images, but labels the entire image. So, it is like labeling a bag of images with a label instead of having to make a label for each sub-image. In your case, you might be able to construct a matrix of images, i.e. a 10 image x 10 image master image for each of the scans...

Let us know if you do this and if it works well on your data set!